# Insertar el valor de una propiedad de un objeto a una lista de HTML (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, lista, objeto

He creado un objeto y quiero que cada propiedad del objeto muestre su valor en una lista de html. Lo que no me queda claro es como hacerlo, en google vi formas que insertar texto desde el js, pero no es como lo hice yo.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<img src="img/logotitulo.png"/><a href=""></a>

<br>
<br>

<h3>Alisado</h3>
<li class="alisado">
    <ul>tiempo: </ul>
    <ul>Ingredientes: </ul>
    <ul>Herramientas: </ul>
    <ul>Precio: </ul>
</li>

<body>
</body>

</html>


    "use strict"

const alisado = {
    tiempo: "10min",
    ingredientes: ["polvo" , "keratina" , "shampoo"],
    herramientas: ["tijera" , "peine" , "pincel"],
    precio: 100,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como todo en programación existen varias formas de hacer esto. A mi parecer, la manera más básica es ir a buscar con javascript un elemento html por medio de su ID y luego colocar el contenido en él

Lo primero que hay que establecer es el cuando queremos volcar el contenido, puede ser cuando se presione un botón o cuando se cargue el documento (entre otras muchas alternativas). Supongamos que queremos hacerlo cuando se cargue el documento.

Para esto debes tener claro que un documento html se lee de arriba hacia abajo, entonces tienes que preocuparte de que los elementos html se hayan cargado antes de manipularlos. Esto se hace a través de Eventos, los eventos son funciones que se gatillan por agentes externos, como lo es el usuario o el navegador. Yo utilizaría esto:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ColocarValores);
```

Esto hace que la función "ColocarValores" se ejecute cuando el contenido del documento ha sido cargado

Luego tenemos que poner la estructura hmtl que va a tener el contenido, en tu código tienes un pequeño error, pones un "li" antes de los "ul", esto es a la inversa.

Entonces el código te quedaría:

```
<ul class="alisado">
    <li>tiempo: <span id="Tiempo"></span></li>
    <li>Ingredientes:  <span id="Ingredientes"></span></li>
    <li>Herramientas:  <span id="Herramientas"></span></li>
    <li>Precio:  <span id="Precio"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Colocamos un span con su respectiva Id en cada item para luego dentro de él colocar los valores

Creamos la función colocar valores:

```
function ColocarValores() {
        document.getElementById("Tiempo").innerHTML = alisado.tiempo;
        document.getElementById("Ingredientes").innerHTML = alisado.ingredientes;
        document.getElementById("Herramientas").innerHTML = alisado.herramientas;
        document.getElementById("Precio").innerHTML = alisado.precio;
    }
```

Utilizamos la función document.getElementById para buscar nuestros span y con innerHTML colocamos texto dentro de él. También podríamos haber utilizado la función queryselector, por ejemplo:

```
document.querySelector("#tiempo").innerHTML = alisado.tiempo;
```

Fíjate que en este caso antes de la Id va un #, si en vez de id hubiéramos ocupado una clase iría un punto, ya que esta función funciona como un selector de css.

El código completo sería:

```
<h3>Alisado</h3>
<ul class="alisado">
    <li>tiempo: <span id="Tiempo"></span></li>
    <li>Ingredientes:  <span id="Ingredientes"></span></li>
    <li>Herramientas:  <span id="Herramientas"></span></li>
    <li>Precio:  <span id="Precio"></span></li>
</ul>

<script>
    const alisado = {
        tiempo: "10min",
        ingredientes: ["polvo", "keratina", "shampoo"],
        herramientas: ["tijera", "peine", "pincel"],
        precio: 100,
    }
      

    function ColocarValores() {
        document.getElementById("Tiempo").innerHTML = alisado.tiempo;
        document.getElementById("Ingredientes").innerHTML = alisado.ingredientes;
        document.getElementById("Herramientas").innerHTML = alisado.herramientas;
        document.getElementById("Precio").innerHTML = alisado.precio;
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ColocarValores);
</script>
```

Comment: wow! terrible lo tu explicación, gracias por tomarte el tiempo de poder explicármela de esta manera. Gracias!